# Custom implementation of ILogger

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In my project I often add prefixes to my log messages.

Currently I am doing this with

```cs
      logger.LogDebug(prefix + " some message");
```

I thought it would be a good way to implement a custom logger where I set the prefix and the logger itself attaches it every time it logs something.

So I created my custom logger class and implemented the ILogger interface. But I do not understand how to use the

```cs
    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
```

method to add the prefix (which is a member of the custom logger class).

My full code is:

```cs
      public class CustomLogger : ILogger
      {

        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private string _logPrefix;

        public CustomLogger(ILogger logger)
        {
          _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _logPrefix = null;
        }

        public ILogger SetLogPrefix(string logPrefix)
        {
          _logPrefix = logPrefix;
          return this;
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
          return _logger.BeginScope(state);
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
          return _logger.IsEnabled(logLevel);
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
          _logger.Log(logLevel, eventId, state, exception, formatter);
        }

      }
```

Comment: Something like `Func<TState, Exception, string> custom = (s, e) => _logPrefix + formatter(s, e)`? And replace `_logger.Log(...formatter)` with `_logger.Log(...custom)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I think It's not a good way to do that, "prefix" will be duplicated a lot. Why don't you use [Log Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#log-scopes) instead?

```
public IActionResult GetById(string id)
{
    TodoItem item;
    using (_logger.BeginScope("Message attached to logs created in the using block"))
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(LoggingEvents.GetItem, "Getting item {ID}", id);
        item = _todoRepository.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning(LoggingEvents.GetItemNotFound, "GetById({ID}) NOT FOUND", id);
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
    return new ObjectResult(item);
}
```

Output

```
info: TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController[1002]
      => RequestId:0HKV9C49II9CK RequestPath:/api/todo/0 => TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetById (TodoApi) => Message attached to logs created in the using block
      Getting item 0
warn: TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController[4000]
      => RequestId:0HKV9C49II9CK RequestPath:/api/todo/0 => TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController.GetById (TodoApi) => Message attached to logs created in the using block
      GetById(0) NOT FOUND
```

Currently, you can't change the logging template, it's the limitation of built-in basic logging in Asp.net Core. For more powerful one, you can try [Serilog](https://serilog.net/), keep using `ILogger` interface and change some line of code in `program.cs` class

You should also look at this [Benefits of Structured Logging vs basic logging](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312197/benefits-of-structured-logging-vs-basic-logging)

Answer (score 15):

I think you should not call a _logger in a custom logger.

It would be a circular call on runtime and the result would be "prefix: prefix: prefix: prefix: prefix: prefix: prefix: prefix: ..."

Simply, you can create a simple logger and implement a log writter such as Console, database writter, log4net, ...

Now first, you should change your custom logger like below:

```cs
    public class CustomLogger : ILogger
    {
        private readonly string CategoryName;
        private readonly string _logPrefix;

        public CustomLogger(string categoryName, string logPrefix)
        {
            CategoryName = categoryName;
            _logPrefix = logPrefix;
        }

        public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
        {
            return new NoopDisposable();
        }

        public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
        {
            string message = _logPrefix;
            if (formatter != null)
            {
                message += formatter(state, exception);
            }
            // Implement log writter as you want. I am using Console
            Console.WriteLine($"{logLevel.ToString()} - {eventId.Id} - {CategoryName} - {message}");
        }

        private class NoopDisposable : IDisposable
        {
            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

The second step, create a logger provider:

```cs
     public class LoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
        {     
            public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
            {                
                return new CustomLogger(categoryName, "This is prefix: ");
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
            }
        }
```

The third step, in Configure from Startup.cs:

```cs
    loggerFactory.AddProvider(new MicroserviceLoggerProvider());
```

Comment: Well that would be a possibility. I just thought of the log prefix to be more like an extension. I get dependency injected ILogger<T> in my controllers and my though was to write such a wrapper/extension to avoid my current implementation of log methods in the controller like LogDebug(string msg), LogInfo(string msg) all calling eg. logger.LogDebug(prefix + msg). I was surprised to not find the LogDebug etc methods in the ILogger interface.

Comment: If that is an extension, how is a proxy class to wrap ILogger then we call proxyLogger.LogDebug(msg). The proxy class adds prefix before call real ILoger instance?

Comment: Yes, that sounds closer to my initial intention. Just don't know how to do this and though implementing ILogger would be the way.

Answer (score 5):

Implement an extensions for adding `prefix` to log records.

```
    public static class LogExtensions
    {
        public static void PrefixLogDebug(this ILogger logger, string message, string prefix = "Edward", params object[] args)
        {
            logger.LogDebug($"{prefix} {message}");
        }
    }
```

Useage:

```
        _log.PrefixLogDebug("Log From Prefix extension");
        _log.PrefixLogDebug("Log From Prefix extension", "New Prefix");
```